# Apostrophe after a surname

Tags: apostrophe, surnames

There is a lot of statistical criteria/tests (statistics) named after a statistician/mathematician/biologist/economist, etc. But for instance, [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friedman_test) and [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mauchly%27s_sphericity_test) examples have different spelling...
*Do I have to write an apostrophe after a surname in such a situation or not?*

Comment: Find what someone else wrote and use that.

Comment: [Wilcoxon's Signed-Rank Test](http://books.google.ru/books?id=VoWIIOKVzR4C&lpg=PA256&dq=nemenyi%20post&pg=PA215#v=onepage&q=nemenyi%20post&f=true) vs [this](http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/sas/whatstat/whatstat.htm)

Comment: An interesting case.  There is a theorem that is often incorrectly written *Stoke's Theorem*.  It should be *Stokes' Theorem* or *Stokes's Theorem*, since the man's name was *Stokes*.

Comment: [an example](http://jmlr.csail.mit.edu/papers/volume9/garcia08a/garcia08a.pdf)

Answer (score 2):

There's an interesting discussion on this topic in [Wikipedia talk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia_talk%3aNaming_conventions_%28theorems%29).

Their conclusion:

> I guess we just have to live with the fact that some theorems
>   traditionally have apostrophes (Goedel's incompleteness theorem) and
>   other's don't (Tietze extension theorem); it doesn't make sense to
>   have a general rule of style there.

Go with tradition if you can find it, or with whatever [manual of style](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia%3aManual_of_Style) you follow otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you refer to it, eg. "Fermat's last theorem" but "the Goldbach conjecture"

Comment: The Goldbach conjecture is sometimes written as Goldbach's conjecture, but you'd never say, The Fermat's last theorem. (unless you were trying to distinguishing it from your cousin Fermat's theorem.

Comment: @Sam - yes if you wrote is as Goldbach's conjecture you would add the apostrophe. It was the first one I could think of that was generally "THE ....."

Comment: Doppler effect comes to mind. It would seem strange to say Doppler's effect. Ohm's Law, conversely, would sound funny as The Ohm Law.